# condtional statement with missing values

Tags: r

I have got a dataframe q. In a for-loop I am trying to print the value for mnt_for under the condition that diff is not 'no'.

I get this message:
Error in if (!q$diff[j] == "no") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

How can I handle the missing value cases (in which I am most interested)

```
for(j in 1:nrow(q)) {

  if (!q$diff[j]=='no'){
    print(q[j,6])
  }

} 


    res_id        lud snow_mountain snow_mountain mnt mnt_for diff
67    3822 2018-02-12           160           160 160     160   no
68    3822 2018-02-13            NA            NA 162     160 <NA>
69    3822 2018-02-14            NA            NA 163     160 <NA>
```

Comment: When I use your data with `diff` as a factor then everything seems to work fine (no errors). Could you add `dput` of the same three lines?

Comment: should work: `!q$diff[j] == "no" || is.na(q$diff[j])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
 for(j in 1:nrow(q)) {
   if (!is.na(q$diff[j]) & !q$diff[j]=='no'){
      print(q[j,6])
   }
 }
```

Might need a double `&&` in the middle, kind of hard to test with no sample data

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution might be

```
print(q[!q$diff %in% c(NA,"no"),6])
```